# Remove single word from file - bash

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to remove php* from the yum.conf of my server. The line in question is as follows:

```
exclude=bind-chroot courier* dovecot* exim* filesystem httpd* mod_ssl* mydns* mysql* nsd*  php* proftpd* pure-ftpd* spamassassin* squirrelmail*
```

I use the following command to remove php*:

```
sed -i "s/"php*"//g" /etc/yum.conf
```

This however removes only **php** and leaves the * behind. How do I remove the ***** as well?

Comment: I think you need to escape it: `\*` since the asterisk (`*`) is a special character

Comment: `echo "php*php*helloworldphp*" | sed 's/php\*//g'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` is a special character, so you have to escape it. Also, you have not quoted the command correctly. It should be like this:

```
sed  's/php\*//g' file
```